# Each entry continuous on a given set, does it mean this vector is continuous on this set?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $z_a$ be a vector in $U \subseteq {\mathbb R}^n$ and each entry $z_a^{(i)}$  ($i \in \{1,\dotsb,n\}$) continuously change w.r.t. $a \in V \subseteq {\mathbb R}^m$.

Then, is the vector $x_a$ continuous on $V$?

PS: Here is the definition of continuity for a map $f: U \to V$, where $U \subseteq {\mathbb R}^n$ and $V \subseteq {\mathbb R}^m$. Given a $x_0 \in U$, if $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $\|f(x) - f(x_0)\| < \varepsilon$ for all $\|x - x_0\| < \delta$, then $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. If $f$ is continuous for every $x_0 \in U$, then $f$ is continuous on $U$. The norm is not specified since all the norms in finite dimensional space are equivalent (in the sense of convergence).

Comment: do you know the definition for continuous function from $U\subseteq\Bbb R^m$ to $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: @Thanks, I have re-edited this problem.

Comment: @janmarqz I think that (I mean the proposition, not the definition) would be true, but not pretty sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By noting that 
$$||z_y-z_a||=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m\left(z_y^{(i)}-z_a^{(i)}\right)^2},$$ 
then by taking 
$$|z_y^{(i)}-z_a^{(i)}|<\frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{m}},\qquad (1)$$ 
for each $i$  we can achieve $||z_y-z_a||<\varepsilon$, since
\begin{eqnarray*}
||z_y-z_a||&=&\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m\left(z_y^{(i)}-z_a^{(i)}\right)^2}\\
&<&\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m\left(\frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{m}}\right)^2}\\
&<&\sqrt{m\left(\frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{m}}\right)^2}\\
&<&\varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}

We can arrive at equation $(1)$, because each $z_a^{(i)}$ is continuous and by taking the suitable $\delta^{(i)}$ such that $||y-a||<\delta$, where $\delta=\min\{\delta^{(1)},...,\delta^{(n)}\}$.

Then for each $\varepsilon>0$ exists a $\delta>0$ such that $||z_y-z_a||<\varepsilon$, if  $||y-a||<\delta$, hence $z_a$ is continuous at $a$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Janmarqz! Great answers!

Comment: I edit your answer with adding the first paragraph to explain why we only consider the 2-norm.

Comment: ok, @Ryan, its seems that another editors agreed not to approve your edits but the benefits you received... are done, Thanks!